# DAO.Recordset.RecordCount property not working as expected

Tags: ms-access, recordset

I am running a query from input from a form.  It is to extract records from 1 table, where the table is joined to 3 others.
It does successfully extract the record. In this case there is only 1 record and the query does find it. 
The problem is that every time I run this code, I get one more RecordCount.
So the first time I run it, the RecordCount is 1 and debug.print gives me the correct information.  The second time I run it, the RecordCount is 2 and debug.print gives me the correct information but twice.  The third time ... 3 and 3, etc. 
It doesn't matter if I close the form (from which I get my variables) and reload it. The number keeps climbing.  I closed Access and reopened it and the number keeps climbing - it didn't reset to 1 record found.

The query selects records depending on a ProductID where the (qtyordered - qtyproduced > 0) and the records are sorted by priority of the customers.

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim db As DAO.Database

    Dim findCSQL As String

    findCSQL = "SELECT tblWarehouseTransfers.WTRProductID, tblOrderDetails.ODEPriority, tblOrderDetails.ODEQuantityOrdered, " _
                        & " tblOrderDetails.ODEQtyProduced, tblCustomers.CompanyName " _
                & " FROM  tblCustomers INNER JOIN (tblOrders INNER JOIN (tblWarehouseTransfers INNER JOIN tblOrderDetails " _
                        & " ON tblWarehouseTransfers.WTRProductID = tblOrderDetails.ODEProductFK) " _
                        & "  ON tblOrders.ORDOrderID = tblOrderDetails.ODEOrderID) ON tblCustomers.ID = tblOrders.ORDCustomerID " _
                & " WHERE (((tblWarehouseTransfers.WTRProductID) = " & Chr$(34) & Me!cboTransferProductID & Chr$(34) & ")) " _
                & " AND ((tblOrderDetails.ODEQuantityOrdered - tblOrderDetails.ODEQtyProduced)> 0) " _
                & " ORDER BY tblOrderDetails.ODEPriority "


    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(findCSQL)

    rs.MoveFirst
    Debug.Print rs.RecordCount

    Do While Not rs.EOF
      Debug.Print ("product ID: " & rs!WTRProductID & " qty ordered: " & rs!ODEQuantityOrdered & " customer name:  " & rs!CompanyName)
      rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
```

How can I empty the recordset and start fresh each time the subroutine is run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My memory might be off since it's been a long time since I've worked with RecordSets, but I think you had to traverse the records before the RecordCount property gave you the correct information.

So try it this way:

```
rs.MoveLast
Debug.Print rs.RecordCount
rs.MoveFirst
```

From [How to: Count the Number of Records in a DAO Recordset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243791(v=office.12).aspx)

> The value of the RecordCount property equals the number of records that have **actually been accessed.**

Comment: Thanks Lars. Unfortunately, that didn't help.  (The number has now climbed to 27! errrrr! That's how many iterations of different scenarios I've tried.)

Comment: @LesProgrammer That's how many records you have from your query.

Comment: No, there is only 1 record.  It is now displayed 27 times, i.e. the Do While Loop does 27 loops because it thinks that's how many records there are.  Next time I run the code, it will loop 28 times and print the found record 28 times - not 28 different records.

Comment: @LesProgrammer The code provided and the results suggests otherwise.

Comment: That's why I'm so frustrated.  The table that the found record is in (i.e. tblOrderDetails) only has 9 records in total.  I've only populated it with a little bit of test data.

Comment: @LesProgrammer Try taking your sql query and run it inside the Access query window.  Analyze it from there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I was able to track down the problem.  The code works perfectly.  In testing, I was adding a record to one of the joined tables before getting to the code in question.  Your suggestion pointed me to what I should have known in the beginning.  Sorry for wasting your time.  And thanks.